# Off the shelf programmable USB

Tags: embedded, usb, dongle

Is there a way to create a programmable USB just using off the shelf USB dongles?

This question: [Programmable USB dongles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377240/programmable-usb-dongles) has answers relating getting "programmable" USBs. But I just want to use an off the shelf USB. It's like this: http://www.pololu.com/product/1336 but just using off the shelf USB device.

Preferably, once the USB is plugged in, an "app" can be ran off it which can be cross platform. This app can be a GUI app, but I'm fine with it being a CLI app.

Would this question be related to those "portable apps" concept? However I don't want it to be part of another ecosystem.

If it's possible to create off the shelf bootable USB sticks (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) surely there must be a way to run apps.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to look into something the Raspberry PI (e.g. not a "dongle" but a programmable device)? Or do you just want to "Run an application distributed by a USB storage device?" (The App will need to explicitly target each platform or provide a runtime that does.)

Comment: I want to run an application distributed by a USB storage device. But it will be secured and locked to that one application. I know I can just put an EXE into a USB and then run it. But I want the USB to be locked to the app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question well, but I happens to know [Senselock](http://www.senselock.com/en/) offers the embedded dongle, it might could full-fill your request.

Our Russia business partner is using this dongle on their print machines, the SSOP chip can be attached to the circuit broad of the machine and it can function as a normal programmable dongle to protect the control application, you can write part of your code into the dongle. However, you have to input some resources to redesign the circuit broad and do some program develop.

Hope you find it helps. Link for the product as following
http://www.senselock.com/en/productinfor.php?nid=185&id=142&pid=